# Bash ADB Calling an app with a variable

Tags: android, bash, adb

I have an app that, when called, outputs the string it was called with into a toast notification.

Like so:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -e message "Example  String" -n com.rja.utility/.ShowToast
```

I wanted to create a for loop, where it would loop trough lines inside a .txt file and output them using the method above, like this:

```
for i in `cat /somedirectory/ToastQueue.txt`; do
    am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -e message "$i" -n com.rja.utility/.ShowToast > dev/null
done
```

But appareantly that doesn't work, it complains that I have extra parametters.

So my question is, how could I make this work? I can't modify the app, so this should all be done trough the shell or ADB

Comment: I'd try adding `set -x` before the loop so you can see what it is executing after variable expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working:

```
for i in `cat /somedirectory/ToastQueue.txt`; do
    i="\"$i\""
    eval "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -e message $i -n com.rja.utility/.ShowToast > dev/null"
done
```

The message has to be quoted if it has spaces in it, but you can't quote it inside eval or that would exit it, so we quote it before passing it to the app.

Comment: If your answer solved the question consider accepting it.

Comment: I will tomorrow, when it lets me ;D